# Intel NUC8I5BEK compatibility

Tags: intel, compatibility, intel-nuc

Has anyone tried installing Ubuntu Desktop on the [Intel NUC8I5BEK](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits/nuc8i5bek.html)?

The essential specs are:

- Intel Core i5-8259U Quad-Core
- Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655

Does it work (partially)?
And if not everything works, what does work?

Comment: Should work fine.

Comment: thanks for replies/managing the question (pardon the duplication). just wanted to confirm that installation of Ubuntu 18LTS on recently released NUC8i5BEK worked like a charm. this is my first linux experience, and I am very happy with this combination.
further hardware specifications:
Samsung 970 EVO NVMe M.2 drive
1x crucial 16GB DDR4-2400 SODIMM

Comment: Be aware that chromium and chromium derivative (Google Chrome, electron js app, etc.) will not work properly. There is a issue with the GPU.

Comment: I'm having trouble using the VAAPI driver in Gstreamer on an Iris Plus Graphics 655 GPU. It doesn't look like DRM (direct rendering manager) works with that card.